# How to implement the Impulse Based Dynamics for the rigid body dynamics simulation?

Tags: computational-physics, simulation

I am having hard time learning the method of impulse based dynamics developed by [Mirtich](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-03-winter/Papers/ibds.pdf) for rigid body dynamics simulation. Please help me out if any body has any example code(algorithm) of it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. It's not clear what you are asking. Where are you struggling?

Comment: Actually, I am struggling with physics of impulse based dynamics. It doesn't follow the molecular dynamics pattern. I was looking for an step by step algorithm if available anywhere on the internet. or maybe code in any language if available. Just a reference will be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find anything better than a very detailed set of pseudocodes from [Brian Mirtich's Ph.D. thesis](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/mirtich/thesis/mirtichThesis.pdf). In his thesis, almost every algorithm required to be implemented for rigid body simulation is described in this form and should be implementable with enough effort.

The thesis would be, in my opinion, a much better starting point compared to the paper you linked in your question.